# AWS restrict access to specific resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I got a server running on AWS and I want to restrict access to a specific route, such that it can only be accessed by AWS Lambda.

I've read about the AWS VPC and it seems to be what I need, but I don't know how to apply such a configuration for a single route.
Can anyone provide some helpful docs for achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say a "route" ... do you mean something like requests for a specific `POST /some/path/here` on your application?

Comment: Yes, is that possible, or do I need to add my own custom headers?